# How does the view count work on Twitch?

Tags: twitch.tv

How exactly does twitch.tv count the number of views that is displayed next to the "Eye Icon"?

Is it based off IP addresses, Accounts, Cookies or even something completely different? A thing that also Interests me is whether Visits from my own account are also influencing the number or not.

Also When does it refresh? On my account I often see that it takes a pretty long time to refresh the count (sometimes up to 8 hours).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too clear on the specifics, but typically when a website is counting views it's counting unique visits. In the case of twitch it would stand to reason that it may be placing cookies on the users systems to track their unique view.

I would assume that your own account doesn't make it increase, seeing as far as I can tell when I view my own channel while I'm live I don't count as a viewer, unless I'm just not giving it time to update the viewer count.

Answer (score -4):

It counts as session believe it or not. Open up multiple browsers and test it out..

Comment: Little more explanation would be more helpful.